# Build API - Restore nuget packages

Tags: c#, nuget-package-restore, microsoft.build

I created an app that builds all the solutions I have using the Build API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn715758(v=vs.121).aspx).

The problem I am facing, is that it does not trigger the nuget package restore.  Which means that if it's the first time someone is building the source code, or a package has been updated by someone else, it does not automatically update/trigger the package restore on build.

Can't find anything in the documentation, maybe someone else knows something?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: @Flea no not yet, but I haven't tried since.

Answer (score 1):

In the solution explorer (where you see your solution and all projections) right click on the **solution**, not on the project.

In the context menu you'll see

**Enable Nuget Package Restore**

Comment: This is already the case, yet building it doesn't restore the packages.. (using the Build API).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to execute the restore command separately.

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#restore-command

Comment: This doesn't seem right, surely the Build API must have something, do you have a source that states you need to run the restore separately?

Comment: nuget isn't part of msbuild, it's a msbuild task located in your soltuion folder under `.nuget/nuget.target` if you are building the .sln file with msbuild ( and you have nuget package restore enabled) the target should triget and restore the packages.

Comment: if it's not trigering, consider doing package restore manually via the `.nuget/nuget.exe` provided